# Find out what columns are in a trace file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trace

while tackling and unexpected CPU spike that was happening every 10 min one of my colleagues prepared a server side trace as follows:

```
-- Create a Queue
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
declare @DateTime datetime

set @DateTime = '2015-09-03 10:50:00.000'
set @maxfilesize = 10240 --10GB

-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 2, N'H:\profiler\BocssTrace_20150903.trc', @maxfilesize, @Datetime
if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 14, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 15, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 35, @on


-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 9db2b190-7855-4588-be4f-9d6567cfa929'
-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go


/*
--stop trace
exec sp_trace_setstatus 2, 0
--remove trace
exec sp_trace_setstatus 2, 2
*/

SELECT * FROM sys.traces
```

question:

Can I work out exactly what trace columns has he put in this trace, without having access to the .trc file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can utilize the trace catalog views in SQL Server to get information about a given trace. Just pass in the ID of the trace you are interested in, code below pulls trace ID of `1`, which is the default trace.

```
--  Gets all Events for a given trace id
SELECT a.[EventID], b.[name] AS [Even Name], a.[ColumnID], c.[name] AS [Column Name], d.[name] AS [Category]
FROM fn_trace_geteventinfo(<trace ID>) AS a --<<Put the trace ID you are interested in
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS b ON a.EventID = b.Trace_Event_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_columns AS c ON a.ColumnID = c.Trace_Column_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_categories AS d ON b.Category_ID = d.Category_ID
ORDER BY a.[EventID], a.[ColumnID]
```

This will give you the `Event Name` and `Column Name` being used by the trace.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT TOP 1 * FROM fn_trace_gettable('H:\profiler\BocssTrace_20150903.trc', default);

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx

Comment: +1 because it is valid, but as I said, I don't have access to the .trc.

Comment: Actually this would take an extremely long amount of time to run if you have large trace files. Using `fn_trace_gettable` has to read the whole file before it would return the `top 1` row.